# I want to declare an array with variable size and also I want to ask from the user to enter it?

Tags: c++

I'm using C++ language. 
double coordinates [length][5];

Comment: What have you tried so far? Would you please show more of your code?Did you take a look at C++ `new` operator?

Comment: You can not declare an array of variable length unless you do dynamic memory allocation.  Dynamic memory allocation on an embedded platform is not a good idea, so it is better to fix the 'length' of the array to a sensible limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to dynamically allocate it.

```
int length;
double **coordinates;
cin >> length;
coordinates = new double*[length];
for (int i = 0; i < length; i ++ {
    coordinates[i] = new double[5];
}
```

Comment: so then I have to close it at the end of my code.

Comment: Indeed you will.

Comment: I'd love to say this will crash, but it won't compile.  cin doesn't exist on an Arduino unless you have got a port of the std lib.   The memory you allocate needs freeing. Finally allowing a user to enter an unrestricted value for length is asking for a crash.  Enter 1,000,000 if your doubt me :)

Comment: That's fair. But it was tagged c++, so that's how I answered. IMHO, this question should be migrated to Stack Overflow.